# How do i add an np.array to an existing np.array without merging the two?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm making a minimax algorithm in Python that plays tic tac toe. I need to store all possible combinations of ndarrays in a different ndarray. I'm storing the board in a numpy array, so an empty board would be `[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]`, an X is a 1 and an O is a -1. I wanted to do it in this way: first off, I have an `np.array([])` to which I add all states possible to happen after the next move, so for the first move on the board it would look something like `[[[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[...]]`. I tried np.append and np.concatenate, but I can't get it to work as I'd like. How should I go about it?

Comment: how have you tried? show some code pls!

Comment: Why do you need to store the combination arrays in an array?  Why not a list?  And if array, what shape of an array to you want?  What will you do with it?  How are you generating 'all states'?  So many questions, and so little information! And one more thing, what do you mean by "without merging"?

Answer (score 0):

The only trick you need is Broadcasting to generate an aditional dimention to stack. (here i've created the first state condition with this aditional dimension but you could broadcast it before stackin

Here a posible solution:

```
import numpy as np


states = np.random.randn(1,3,3)
print(f"actual Shape is: {states.shape}")

for i in range(3):
    newState = np.random.randn(3,3)
    states = np.append(states,newState[None,:,:],axis=0)
    print(f"actual Shape is: {states.shape}")
```

Also you could use `vstack` or `concatenate`

```
states = np.vstack([states,newState[None,:,:]])

states = np.concatenate([states,newState[None,:,:]],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [`np.append`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.append.html). When appending numpy arrays, the arrays should have the same number of dimensions. Hence, in order to get the outcome you want you can proceed like so:

```
import numpy as np

tictactoe = np.zeros(shape=(1, 3, 3)) # create an empty array
n = np.array([[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]]) # example of value to add

tictactoe = np.append(tictactoe, n, axis=0) # adding the value in
print(tictactoe)
```

in order to make the `np.append` work, notice that I am passing one of the boards into the first axis `axis=0` as a three dimensional array `[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]]`. Notice the triple brackets. This should give you an outcome of shape `(2, 3, 3)` where the `2` represents the number of boards you have.

Otherwise here is a basic way of doing it without numpy by simply appending a list:

```
tictactoe = []
n = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
tictactoe.append(n)
print(tictactoe)
```

---

N.b.  As `@hpaulj` noted within the comments, `np.append` with axis is the same as `np.concatenate`. Such iterative uses can be quite slow, and require special care when starting. [Here is a link to a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70144878/list-append-faster-than-np-append).

Comment: `np.append` with `axis` is just a call to `np.concatenate`.  `concatenate` (and family) is best used with a whole list of arrays.  Iterative use like this  is much slower, and requires special care when starting.  See this recent SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70144878/list-append-faster-than-np-append about speeds.

Comment: @hpaulj That is true, however I do think it is an important option to mention. `np.append` is easier to understand / get a hold of. Additionnally given that @ubi has mentioned both `np.append` and `np.concatenate` I though each option should be shown. All in all, you are right, they are exactly the same and they both require special care when starting. Thanks for the link

Comment: My observation from many SO is that `np.append` is easier to mis-understand.   It encourages iterative use copied from the list append.  It isn't a list append clone.

Comment: I'll add your remarks to the answer

Comment: @hpaulj my answer with the for is formulated that way because the OP doesn't give more information about how he/she's trying to concatenate... then I had put some example code ... yes about append, that's why I present other options, but think append is a good way to make code clear, concatenate seems confusing to some people